# Dominating set with vertex cover

Tags: vertex-cover

if we have a Graph (V, E) and for all nodes v_i, v_j exists a path from v_i to v_j can you give me an example of such graph with dominating set size 2 and doesn't have a vertex cover of size 3?

Comment: Please dont dump your homework questions here.

Comment: @nirshahar Sir, this is a question I had in my first term exam and I gave an example and it was wrong and I am trying to learn in order to pass the second term. Please if you don't know how to help and have time to share your unnecessary opinion, don't comment and do something usefull. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. But it looks like a homework dump to me. If you want us to help you, show what you have tried already. Without showing your efforts on solving this question, it looks like you are just dumping the question. Anyways, I would still be glad to help you.understand where u were wrong and to find the right solution, so I would appreciate if you could include it in the question

Comment: One way would be to start with $4$ edges connecting $8$ vertices pairwise, then add edges until you have a dominating set of $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: a cycle of the right size with one more edge. A complete graph of the right size can also work.

Comment: the solution says to put one vertex in the middle as the center of the circle connected with  vertex on the "circuly line" but this is a dominating set of size 1, right?

Comment: If you add a vertex to a dominating set of size 1, it is still a dominating set, so this solution is also possible (though not the one I proposed, but it still works).

Comment: so essentially if the example has k vertices then this means that the graph has a dominating set of size one as well as of size 2, ... , k?

Comment: In the case of a complete graph, yes.

Comment: uh ok I get it now. Many Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, in my last comment, a graph (not necessarily complete) with a vertex adjacent to all other vertices also verify the property you spoke of.